# First button in my html doesnt request post, but the other buttons work fine

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

[This is the webpage i have been working on..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zor8i.png)

Here I have multiple buttons which I got from an ejs for loop(edit buttons, delete buttons). Deleting works fine. But when I click edit, the first edit button doesn't send the post request, but the other buttons do. I cant understand why.....
Following is the serverside code,

```js
  app.post('/todo/edit/:todoId',function(req,res){
    //console.log(req.params.todoId);
    //res.json({url:'todo-edit'});
    res.render('todo-edit',{cat:req.params.todoId});
    console.log('dog');
  });
```

```html
          <form>
            <% for(var i=0;i<todos.length;i++){ %>
              <% if(todos[i].done){ %>
                <li id="strike"><%= todos[i].item %></li><form action="/todo/edit/<%= todos[i]._id %>" method="post"><button type="submit" class="btn1 <%= todos[i]._id %>">-</button><button id=<%= todos[i]._id %> class="btn2">X</button></form>
              <% }else{ %>
                <li id="nonStrike"><%= todos[i].item %></li><form action="/todo/edit/<%= todos[i]._id %>" method="post"><button type="submit" class="btn1 <%= todos[i]._id %>">-</button><button id=<%= todos[i]._id %> class="btn2">X</button></form>
              <% } %>
            <% } %>
        </form>
```

Comment: Do you get an error or simply nothing happens?

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: How does the `todos` array look like?

Comment: but when the other buttons are clicked, they forward me to where i want, only the first button gives this problem

Comment: [ { _id: 5abfa1188665f803c016e334,
    item: 'Watic movie',
    done: false,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5abfa1238665f803c016e335,
    item: 'Go To ell',
    done: true,
    __v: 0 } ]

Comment: items in the array are changed since the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, First of all, for other people here trying to solve this problem. Here is the code in a more readable format

```
      <form>
        <% for(var i=0;i<todos.length;i++){ %>
          <% if(todos[i].done){ %>
            <li id="strike"><%= todos[i].item %></li>
            <form action="/todo/edit/<%= todos[i]._id %>" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="btn1 <%= todos[i]._id %>">-</button>
                <button id=<%= todos[i]._id %> class="btn2">X</button>
            </form>
            <% }else{ %>
                <li id="nonStrike"><%= todos[i].item %></li>
                <form action="/todo/edit/<%= todos[i]._id %>" method="post">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn1 <%= todos[i]._id %>">-</button>
                    <button id=<%= todos[i]._id %> class="btn2">X</button>
                </form>
              <% } %>
            <% } %>
    </form>
```

Secondly,

You have list elements (li) that are not encased within a ul or ol tag which is REALLY bad practice.

Lastly, Due to restrictions in browser technology you are gonna need to look up how to do a "method_override" in order to create your onw "delete" route. So that your action would end up looking similar to this.

action="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>?_method=DELETE"

Hope this sets you on the correct path.

Comment: I did what you said, but it doesnt explain why the first edit button doesnt work and the rest edit buttons work

Comment: What does the todo array look like? It being only the first one it sounds like when you are looping through the array you are starting on -1 instead of 0

Comment: [ { _id: 5abfa1188665f803c016e334, item: 'Watic movie', done: false, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5abfa1238665f803c016e335, item: 'Go To ell', done: true, __v: 0 } ]

Comment: I thought about that too. But when deleting it works fine. Only editing button gives the problem

Comment: And the edit button DOES work on the second item in the database? What happens once you hit the edit button?

Comment: Okay, looking at a project I've recently completed. Your edit route is not Restful compliant. Instead of your edit path being "/todo/edit/<%= todos[i]._id it should be /blogs/<%=todos[i]._id%>/edit

Comment: when I hit the 1st edit button the page just reloads, but when i click the rest edit buttons it forwards me to the correct url

Comment: lastly, you need to do another method override to create a PUT method so you'll have a _?method=put

Comment: can you explain me the purpose of /blog/<%=todos[i]._id%>/edit

Comment: Sure! However, if you look up RESTful routing online you will probably find a much better description than I can give. Basically, you have to think about the edit being DONE ON the object and thus the ID goes first.

Comment: No problem :) hope I helped